# Is there any resizeable limit for a shape in Graphiti?

Tags: javascript, raphael, draw2d, graphiti-js

In the Graphiti example : [Drag And Drop Edit Policy](http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example/edit_policy_constraint)

- When we drag any shape then it is draggble to some limited area that we have defined.
- But when we are going to resize any of the shapes then it got resize outside the dragging limit(no limlt for resize).

Is there any way so that we can limit the resizable property to some extent.

Because we set its dragging limit but not controlling its resize limit. May be is there any way to achieve this.

If anybody know please let me know.Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no limitation for the resize. I try to implement this for the next release.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm looking forward for the next release. Hope it will release soon:)

Comment: Anyways.What will be the expected date of next release?